# Using Monotone Class Theorem to show equality of measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, monotone-class-theorem

Consider the following theorem:

> Theorem: Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space, and let $\mathcal{C}$ a class of subsets of $X$. Supose that $X \in \mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under finite intersections, i.e
> $$
>     A \cap B \in \mathcal{C}, \quad \forall A, B \in \mathcal{C} .
>     $$
> If $\mathcal{D}$ is the smallest class that contains $\mathcal{C}$, and such that is closed under finite differences
> ($\forall A,B\in\mathcal{D}$, $A\backslash B\in\mathcal{D}$) and y increasing limits ($\forall\{E_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\mathcal{D}$ such that $E_1\subseteq E_2\subseteq\ldots$, satisfy that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}E_n\in\mathcal{D}$),  then
> $$
>     \mathcal{D}=\sigma(\mathcal{C})
>     $$
> where $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{C}$.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space, $\pi,\tau$ two measures in that space such that $\pi(\Omega)=\tau(\Omega)=1$, and $\mathcal{C}$ a class of subsets of $\Omega$ such that $\pi(A)=\tau(A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{C}$ it's closed under finite intersections and $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{A}$. Assuming $\Omega\in\mathcal{C}$, show that
$$\forall A\in\mathcal{A},\hspace{0.2cm}\pi(A)=\tau(A)$$

My attempt: Let $\mathcal{D}$ the smallest class that contains $\mathcal{C}$ such that is closed under finite differences and increasing limits, then $\sigma(\mathcal{C})\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{D})$, and by the theorem, $\mathcal{D}=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$, this implies $\sigma(\mathcal{D})=\mathcal{D}$, in particular $\mathcal{D}$ is algebra and by Monotone Class Theorem, $\sigma(\mathcal{D})$ is the smallest monotone class that contains $\mathcal{D}$. I have already show that $M=\{A\in\sigma(\mathcal{D}):\pi(A)=\tau(A)\}$ is monotone class, but to conclude I need to show that $\mathcal{D}\subseteq M$, and I don't know how. Am I on the right track?

Comment: In the last paragraph, you set $\mathcal D$ to be the smallest class containing $\mathcal C$ and closed under finite *intersections* and increasing limits. Did you mean to say that it's the smallest class containing $\mathcal C$ and closed under finite *differences* and increasing limits? Because using differences matches your theorem and allows you to conclude that $\mathcal D=\sigma(\mathcal C)$. Using intersections instead, it's still true that $\sigma(\mathcal C)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal D)$, but not that $\mathcal D=\sigma(\mathcal C)$, and this $\mathcal D$ is not a monotone class.

Comment: @TobyBartels It was a mistake when transferring what I had written in my notebook, I have just corrected it, sorry for the confusion.